Cannot get Lutron Diva dimmer wiring to work
I have a single 2 way switch that has a supply coming into it which then goes to the source.
The previous working switch was wired like so:

When I try connecting the dimmer switch following their directions it doesn't work. This is wired like so:

It was wired to control the outlet which I removed a while back and this now looks like:

I find it strange that the existing switch works. Am I missing something here?

No chance you've swapped your line and load blacks?  Maybe try swapping the red and black on the switch?
